# How to get some kind 'execute' info/ status from SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

The topic related Software is use.

- `Python 3.9.13`
- `psycopg2-binary      2.9.3`
- `SQLAlchemy           1.4.37`
- `PostgreSQL 13+`

I wrote a python script to automate some daily repetition work on my database, so far everything works. Nevertheless i want that SQLAlchemy is more talkative to me.

For instance if i do some`UPDATE` work on my table in the column `client_label` via the `PGadmin 4` Query Tool:

**pgAdmin**

---

```
UPDATE webserver_clients
SET client_label = 'unknown';
```

The response of PGadmin is some kind of status/ info

```
UPDATE 93

Query returned successfully in 104 msec.
```

93 Datapoints updated and i took 104 msec. Nice! Such kind of status/ info would be nice to fetch via `SQLAlchemy` to integrate into some kind of further evaluation and logging in my script. The `msec`info is may not the most important for me, but things like the updated 93 Datapoints are valuable for me.

So i tried to look into the `connection.execute()` object like `satus_info.__dict__` or `satus_info.keys()` but there is so many nested stuff going on. The Examples in the documentation that i saw were only related to queries with responding `rows` which is of course 0.

**script.py**

---

```
<...>
query = sa.text(f'''
    UPDATE webserver_clients
    SET client_label = 'unknown';''')
satus_info = connection.execute(query)
<...>
```

**Question**

---

So my Question is how can i retrieve some more Information or Status about the `UPDATE` process after it was executed from `SQLAlchemy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
attribute sqlalchemy.engine.BaseCursorResult.rowcount
```

This returns the *rowcount* for this result. This is what is *matched* by the query, not necessarily how many rows were *modified*.

*The `rowcount` reports the number of rows matched by the `WHERE` criterion of an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement.*

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.rowcount